# Custom module compiles against different NodeJS version

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, electron, node-gyp

I have built a custom NodeJS module in C++, and I would like to use that in my electron app.
The module compilation using `node-gyp` works fine, and it copies the files in a dedicated directory. I can also install it by referring to the folder in my `package.json` file.

However, when I run the application, I get the following error:

> (node:20800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module '\?\D:\GitProjects\addon-test\local_node_modules\zeelicensenode\zeelicensenodejsaddon.node'
> was compiled against a different Node.js version using
> NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
> NODE_MODULE_VERSION 103. Please try re-compiling or re-installing

The module is compiled on the same Windows machine I am running the application and has only one NodeJS version installed.

> D:\GitProjects\addon-test> node --version
> v16.13.2

As per the [electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules), it uses a different ABI than the native NodeJS binary, so they suggest to build the module in a different way. Following that documentation, I updated the `make.ps1` file of C++ module as follows:

#### make.ps1

```
$env:Path="$($env:APPDATA)\npm;$($env:Path)"

npm install -g node-gyp
node-gyp clean
node-gyp configure

$env:HOME="$($env:USERPROFILE)\.electron-gyp;$($env:HOME)"

node-gyp build --target=18.1.0 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron

copy -Verbose .\build\Release\zeelicensenodejsaddon.node .\dist
```

In my electron application, I have the following dependencies:

### package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
    "zeelicensenodejs": "file:local_node_modules/zeelicensenode"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^3.0.0",
    "electron": "^18.1.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7"
  }
```

The `local_node_modules/zeelicensenode` folder contains the declaration file, package.json file, zeelicensenodejsaddon.node file and a JS file that exports the module. The JS file has these lines:

```js
const license = require('./zeelicensenodejsaddon');
module.exports = license;
```

NODE_MODULE_VERSION 103 refers to the current NodeJS version (18.x), but I do not understand where it is coming from. I have NodeJS 16.x installed on my machine, and as per the [Electron's release information](https://github.com/electron/releases#releases), Electron v18.1.0 also has NodeJS 16.x.

Is there anything I am missing to make this custom module work with Electron?

Comment: the electron release information also lists the module version as 103, I guess as part of its different ABI it uses different module versions to the equivalent version of node

Comment: We have had faced this issue too and it was really frustrating. Hope you have electron rebuild installed. Then try this: `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`  Then you can run this command to rebuild your native module: `node-gyp rebuild --target=6.0.12 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers` Replace electron version with your version and/or architecture too. In some cases just running the first `.cmd` file has worked for us but not in all the cases though

Comment: @Asesh I already tried this but doesn't work. Still get the same error.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh, I missed that column. Thanks for the info.